# Python Pandas read_excel dtype str replace nan by blank ('') when reading or when writing via to_csv

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, nan

Python version: Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
Pandas version: pandas 0.20.2

Hello,

I have a quite simple requirement.
I would like to read an excel file and write a specific sheet to a csv file.
Blank values in the source Excel file should be treated / written as blank when writing the csv file.
However, my blank records are always written as 'nan' to the output file. (without the quotes)

I read the Excel file via method

**read_excel(xlsx, sheetname='sheet1', dtype = str)**

I am specifying dtype because I have some columns that are numbers but should be treated as string. (Otherwise they might lose leading 0s etc)
i.e. I would like to read the exact value from every cell.

Now I write the output .csv file via
**to_csv(output_file,index=False,mode='wb',sep=',',encoding='utf-8')**

However, my result csv file contains nan for all blank cells from the excel file.

What am I missing? I already tried .fillna('', inplace=True) function but it seems to be doing nothing to my data.
I also tried to add parameter na_rep ='' to the to_csv method but without success.

Thanks for any help!

Addendum: Please find hereafter a reproducible example.

Please find hereafter a reproducible example code.
Please first create a new Excel file with 2 columns with the following content:
COLUMNA COLUMNB COLUMNC
01      test
02  test
03      test

(I saved this Excel file to c:\test.xls
Please note that 1st and 3rd row for column B as well as the 2nd row for Column C is blank/empty)

Now here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('c:\\test.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheetname='Sheet1', dtype = str)
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
df.to_csv('c:\\test.csv', index=False,mode='wb',sep=',',encoding='utf-8', na_rep ='')
```

My result is:
 COLUMNA,COLUMNB,COLUMNC
 01,nan,test
 02,test,nan
 03,nan,test

My desired result would be:
COLUMNA,COLUMNB,COLUMNC
01,,test
02,test,
03,,test

Comment: What do you mean by "blank"?

Comment: `df.fillna` didn't work?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: By blank I mean an empty cell in Excel (when reading) gets written to 'nan' (without quotes)
df.fillna('', inplace=True) didn't work.

I will try to work on a reproducible example.

Comment: @panda So it is a `nan` string?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since you are dealing with `nan` strings, you can use the [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : ['nan', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'nan', 'test']})
df.replace('nan', '')

   Col1
0      
1   foo
2   bar
3   baz
4      
5  test
```

All `'nan'` string values will be replaced by the empty string `''`. `replace` is not in-place, so make sure you assign it back:

```
df = df.replace('nan', '')
```

You can then write it to your file using `to_csv`.

---

If you are actually looking to fill NaN values with blank, use `fillna`:

```
df = df.fillna('')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works!
Would you be able to explain why fillna() doesn't work?

Comment: @panda `df.fillna` explicitly looks for `np.nan` (it is a float number with a special bit representation), whereas `'nan'` is just a string. Also, you can consider marking this answer accepted if it helped. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Is there any specific reason/added value that read_excel would replace blank/empty cells with 'nan' string instead of leaving them blank?

Comment: @panda A little searching, and I found it's a bug apparently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157939/pandas-read-csv-fills-empty-values-with-string-nan-instead-of-parsing-date

Comment: I didn't like the idea of replacing 'nan' with '' since that doesn't seem to make the distinction between legitimate 'nan' strings and empty cells, but `df = pd.read_excel.fillna('')` worked well, thanks.

Comment: This method will replace all "nan" string, so it's not safe. Don't use it.

Comment: That's what the question asks, and that is the answer provided

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, and the options for `replace` or `fillna` did not work. (df.info() showed that the fields where NaN was displayed were float64). The `na_filter = False option` worked for me. It would work like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel("myexcelfile.xlsx", na_filter = False)
```

You can read more about the `na_filter` option in the pandas `read_excel` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and used the option  keep_default_na=False in read_excel.
df = pd.read_excel(content, sheet_name=sheet, header=[0], keep_default_na=False)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31019150)

Comment: very useful though