# Pandas Recognizes Empty Cell From CSV as EMPTY SPACE Instead of nan

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nan

I have a Data Frame that I read in as,

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'path\file.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

This is how it looks,

```
Machine ID  Machine June    July   August
0   100     ABC      10     12     nan
1   100     ABC      nan    15     15
2   101     CDQ      12            20
3   101     CDQ      15     32     11
```

And data types:

```
Machine ID  int 64
Machine     object
June        float64
July        object
August      float64
```

When I try to `groupby` like this,

```
machine_group = df.groupby(['Machine ID','Machine'])\['June', 'July', 'August'].sum()\
                    .reset_index()
```

I only get `June` and `August` as `July` has an empty space/ empty string.

```
           ID    Machine     June    August 
0         100     ABC        10      15
1         101     CDQ        27      31
```

Therefore, I tried the [fllowoing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518735/convert-strings-to-float-in-all-pandas-columns-where-this-is-possible),

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'ignore')
```

This did not convert my `July` column to numeric/float64.

Next, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445241/replacing-blank-values-white-space-with-nan-in-pandas),

```
df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)
```

This also, did not work. I still have the empty space in my data frame. Not sure what to do.

I was reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867028/get-pandas-read-csv-to-read-empty-values-as-empty-string-instead-of-nan), seems like I have the inverse issue of this.

How can I make sure I have `nan` instead of empty string? because that empty string in `July` column makes the column to be `object` and it doesn't count for aggregation in `groupby` clause.

(I checked the original .csv file and that exact line, it is normal empty cell as others, where other empty cells get read in as `nan` and this particular one is not)

Any suggestions would be nice.

Comment: df = df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)

Comment: try  `df['July'] = pd.to_numeric(df.July, errors='coerce')`

Comment: @Wen I did that and it still shows `July` as `object`.  And when I do `group by` I still don't get `July` :(

Comment: Try to look at na_values  in pd.read_csv

Comment: @Wen yes, I have been reading some [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), but what confusing me is it says I have to pass a `dict` for `na_values`.

Comment: @ALollz when I tired what you suggested, it did converted all the columns that has empty to `nan`. And even converted all columns that have an empty space. In machine column some of them I have a space in names, so, it did converted that into `float64`. Also, I don't get any results in my `groupby` clause. I get an empty dataframe. I am confused now.

Comment: @Wen since you suggested `na_values` I found (this)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157939/pandas-read-csv-fills-empty-values-with-string-nan-instead-of-parsing-date] and #bdiamante's answer suggests while reading `na_values = ['nan', '']` still did not work. I still have that empty spot.

Comment: Can you please provide the contents of your `.csv` file?

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought was to drop the row that has an empty space in `July` column. Although I did not want to because what if I have a significant value in other columns that is needed for analysis.

However, for now, I found a solution just because of empty space, `July` is `object` type. Using the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952790/convert-pandas-series-from-dtype-object-to-float-and-errors-to-nans),

```
df['July'] = pd.to_numeric(df['July'], errors='coerce')
```

I can manually transform into a `float64` type. And I could get my `groupby` to work.

However, it would be ideal to deal with it when I read in the data frame such as `na_values = ['nan', '']` and as @Nick Tallant suggested. Unfortunately, they did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might try specifying the data types for the columns, so that any empty spaces/strings are NaN. You can try using `dtype` or `converters`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'path\file.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
                , dtype={'June': int, 'July':int, 'August':int})
```

`df = pd.read_csv(r'path\file.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1"
                    , converters={'June': int, 'July':int, 'August':int})`

Edit: You can also try numpy dtypes as well (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html)

Comment: when I do `'July':int'`, I get an error: `ValueError: cannot safely convert passed user dtype of int32 for float64 dtyped data in column`. Not sure, why it behaves this way!

Comment: @user9431057 Can you post a few sample rows of the csv? And also, have you tried different encodings?

Comment: My file is huge and only one place has an empty value as posted above.

Comment: @user9431057 After looking at the docs - converters might work instead of dtype

Comment: @user9431057 Int column can not contain nulls